# Finding the sum of non-real roots of a polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

$$x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+ \cdots a_0=0$$

Given a polynomial, how does one find the sum of non-real roots of the polynomial? 
I was wondering whether there is any closed form solution for it?

For instance, for $P(x)=x^4-8x^3+24x^2-32x-7040$, one can only carefully factorize and check for the solutions. Any text regarding this would be very great.